# Rounding a Variant

Tags: excel, rounding, variant, vba

Why does a number rounded to 1 digit still write to Excel with many digits.

For instance:

```
dim myvar as variant
dim mysingle as single
dim myrange as range

mysingle = 4567.23494376
myvar = round(mysingle,1)

myrange = "A1"
myrange.value = myvar
```

Even though I'm writing `myvar` which has been rounded to one digit to cell A1, although the cell displays 4567.2, clicking on the cell shows the entire value with all the digits to the right of the mantissa in the formula bar.

Should I expect this behavior?

Comment: Yes and no .. it depends https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/214118/how-to-correct-rounding-errors-in-floating-point-arithmetic

Comment: This code is syntactically wrong. `myrange = "A1"` will not work while `myrange` is `DIM`ed as a `Range`. And since `Excel` uses floating point in `Double` precision, you should not using `Single` in VBA for `Excel`.

Comment: Yes. When you cast the Single `4567.2` to a Double (which is how Excel uses numbers), the value will be `4567.2001953125`, which is what you see in the cell.  You can see this with:  `Debug.Print myvar, CDbl(myvar)`

Comment: @AxelRichter  Thank Axel for pointing that out.

My actual code was:
    Dim mystring As String
    mystring = "A1"

    Range(mystring).Value = mysingle

Answer (score 4):

Try `myvar = WorksheetFunction.Round(mysingle, 1)`

instead of  `myvar = round(mysingle,1)`

---

Please also see the information below provided by @**YowE3K**

`WorksheetFunction.Round` always returns a value of type `Variant/Double`, while `Round` returns a value of the same type as the `input parameter` (`Single` in this case).

Comment: You might like to edit the answer to point out that `WorksheetFunction.Round` always returns a value of type `Variant/Double`, while `Round` returns a value of the same type as the input parameter (`Single` in this case).

Comment: Thanks YowE3K, I'll add these information to give an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Using singles is nearly always a bad idea - Excel uses Doubles - converting singles to doubles leads to trouble - this code works as you expect for the double but gives your unexpected answer with a single without involving Round

```
    Sub roundit()
Dim myvar As Variant
Dim myDouble As Double
Dim mySingle As Single
myDouble = 4567.23494376
mySingle = 4567.2
myvar = Round(myDouble, 1)

Range("a1").Value = myvar
Range("a2").Value = mySingle
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Charles. I thought I was being smart using singles to save memory.